# Wrong output to terminal in C code (with argc)

Tags: c

I'm having a problem in the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    char max;
    char *max_ptr = &max;
    *max_ptr = 3;

    char *tmp = (argc > 1)? argv[1]: max_ptr;
    int w = atoi(tmp);
    printf("%i",w);

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is: if there is 1 argument (argc > 1), then that argument is printed in the terminal. If there is no argument (argc = 1) then the value to be printed is '3'.

When I write arguments, the program prints them. However, when I don't write an argument, the output is '0'.

Can anyone explain me why? I'm new to C and pointers, so please bear with me.

Comment: max is a char, with no terminator. Passing a char pointer with no terminator to `atoi` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `max` the value `3` (an integer representation of a single character), not `'3'` (a single character) or `"3"` (a null-terminated string).

Calling `atoi` on this value causes undefined behavior, because the `char*` you are passing it is not actually pointing to a null-terminated string as required.

Undefined behavior means, that anything could happen, for example it could print `0`.

You are really making this more complicated than required:

```
const char *tmp = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "3";
```

Note the double quotes, making this a (null-terminated) string literal, rather than a single character literal.